# Selenium-How to get data from excel sheet and write that to webpage?

Tags: excel, xpath, selenium

Hi, the scenario here is I want to enter some values in a text field in the page, and before that I need to find the text field using xpath.

So here I have values and xpaths of those fields in an excel sheet. How do I get the above code to work? Neither snippet works or shows any error.

```
Cell cells = null;
            Cell idcell=null;
            if (checking.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxxxxxxxxxx")){
                System.out.println("Checking xxxxxxxxxxxx");

                if (checking.equalsIgnoreCase("yyyyyyyyyyyy")){
                for (int cols = 0; cols < sheet.getColumns(); cols++) {
                    cells = sheet.getCell(cols, rows);
                    idcell=sheet.getCell(cols,rows);
WebElement element_BuyCategory = driver.findElement(By.xpath(idcell.getContents()));
    element_BuyCategory.sendKeys(cells.getContents());
        System.out.println("xpath ok");
                    }
```

Responses would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post an [SSCCE](http://www.sscce.org). Without any kind of error message or being able to reproduce the issue, nobody will be able to help you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suppose you know how to extract the data from the excel that you post in your code above.

For the part of find the text box in the page using XPath, I think is more easy if you user CSS-Selectors instead of XPath because XPath its a little difficult for newbies in this fields and tends to change.

If we take the text box that appears in the upper right corner of the page of StackOverflow that executes a search of example , the HTML code in the page its the following :

```
<input class="textbox" type="text" value="" size="28" maxlength="240" tabindex="1" placeholder="search" name="q" autocomplete="off"></input>
```

My suggestion is use the following code :

```
Cell cells = null;
Cell idcell=null;

if (checking.equalsIgnoreCase("xxxxxxxxxxxxx"))
{
    System.out.println("Checking xxxxxxxxxxxx");

    if (checking.equalsIgnoreCase("yyyyyyyyyyyy")){
        for (int cols = 0; cols < sheet.getColumns(); cols++) 
        {
            cells = sheet.getCell(cols, rows);
            idcell = sheet.getCell(cols,rows);            
            WebElement element_BuyCategory = driver.findElement(
                                           By.cssSelector(
                                           "#search div input.textbox ");

             /* Other way is find the element by its name, if its have a name  */
             WebElement element_BuyCategory_by_Name = driver.findElement(
                                           By.name("q");

            element_BuyCategory.sendKeys(cells.getContents());
            System.out.println("xpath ok");
         }
}
```

If for some case you want to use XPath the you need to substitute the line of find the element with the next line :

```
/* If it's the only text box with this class or it's the first, I repeat this is a   example */
WebElement element_BuyCategory = driver.findElement
                                 By.xpath("//input[contains(@class,'textbox')"));
```

I hope that the examples explained above can help you.

Comment: Hi Vkt0r, Thanks for your response its really help full. but the point here is i want that loop statement to identify number of xpaths which is there in excel sheet and then i want the web browser to find the web element and then in the next line i should enter the values to that web element accordingly which is also present in the excel sheet. I know it would be little confusing please try if it is possible. i think nobody would have tried this way.. it reduces huge amount of coding.

Comment: I don't understand very well what do you want exactly. Look if you have trouble with the translation of XPath to CSS Selectors I recommend you a simple translator located in [link](https://github.com/santiycr/cssify), is really very useful